# functions are object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var obj = {};
var fn = function(){};
obj.prop = "some value";
fn.prop = "some value";
assert( obj.prop == fn.prop, "Both are objects, both have the property." );
assert(typeof(obj) === 'object', "Yes its an object");
assert(typeof(fn) === 'object', "why is this not an object");
```

I heard from some people around that `functions are objects` and this is what i am believing so far, but why is the first condition `passes` well and third one `fails`.

Comment: Yes, yes they are. Now, what is the *result* of `typeof fn`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because the *direct* type of a function is `"function"`.

However, you missed this assertion:

```
fn instanceof Object // true
```

Btw, types such as `"number"` and `"string"` are strictly *not* descendants of `Object`, even though they are *like* objects in the sense that they have methods; just one of those things that makes JavaScript interesting :)

See also: [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) and its range of values.

Answer (score 8):

Functions *are* objects, but they are a particular *type* of object.  `typeof(fn)` should evaluate to "function", which is a sub-type of "object".